# Kindle Fire HD (Tate) boot loop, after attempt to install CM

Tags: amazon-kindle

I attempted to install Cyanogenmod on my Tate, according to the directions in the Wiki.

https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_tate

At Step 3, number 5 (fastboot -i 0x1949 oem recovery), the kindle does not boot to recovery, but just shows the logo, and then goes back to Fastboot, even with a non-fastboot cable.

If I restart without a cable attached, I get a boot loop (even when I hold down the volume button, as described).

Perhaps this is relevant: before I started all of this, my Tate was already rooted. Was it stupid to apply the exploit in that case? I only realized this later. If so, is there any way out?

BTW, I'm on Linux, have a working adb and a fastboot cable.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing related to rooting ought to affect recovery or the bootloader.  Sounds like you might need to re-flash the recovery.

Comment: Got it! I did re-flash the recovery, and that seemed to take care of it. Before that, I also went

`fastboot -i 0x1949 oem idme bootmode 4000`

However, that took a while but then said it failed, so maybe just re-flashing the recovery by itself was what did it.

Comment: Toby, as you found a solution you might wish to go ahead and [answer your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), then accept it – so other users with the same issue can identify it as solution. Please include the steps for the process then. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I did re-flash the recovery, and that seemed to take care of it.

Before that, I also went

`fastboot -i 0x1949 oem idme bootmode 4000`

However, that took a while but then said it failed, so maybe just re-flashing the recovery by itself was what did it.